# contentOffset.x doesn't work in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift

I have horizontal scrolling in a `webView`. I need that my text in the `webView` to be shown from the position `x = 1000`. For this I use the following line:

```
self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = 1000
```

The problem is that this line only works in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method, and if I use it in method, then after that I cannot scroll my `webView` because it is always on `x = 1000`

In `viewDidLoad` the line does not work. Where I need to write it so that it works at the start of `webView`, and then I can scroll my webView correctly.

code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        webView?.scrollView.delegate = self
        
        do {
            guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
                else {
                    print ("File reading error")
                    return
            }
            
            let headerString = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\" />"
            let string =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
            let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            webView.loadHTMLString(headerString+string, baseURL: baseUrl)
            webView.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
            
            self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = 1000
        }
        catch {
            print ("File HTML error")
        }
    }

}
```

This line also does not work in `viewDidLoad`

```
webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 0), animated: false)
```

Comment: You need to wait until the web view has *finished* loading the content. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview

Comment: @DonMag I add this `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation:WKNavigation!) { self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = 700 }` but function not called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that - because a ***lot*** goes on when a `WKWebview` loads, formats, and displays html - it's not going to be quite as straightforward as you might hope.

Couple approaches that I've found playing around with this...

First, in order to get `didFinish navigation` to be called, make sure your controller conforms to `WKNavigationDelegate`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate { }
```

and, set the web view's delegate to self in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Then, two options...

Option 1 -- Animate the Offset. I don't know your needs, but this might work for you, and, it would inform the user that he's looking at an already-scrolled portion of the html:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 0), animated: true)
}
```

Option 2 -- Delay setting the Offset. It seems we need a tiny delay, 0.01 seconds appears to work:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
        webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = 1000
    }
}
```

Depending on your actual html content, that may appear as an abrupt flicker, so...

Option 3 - Delay setting the Offset and then *fade-in* the view. In `viewDidAppear()` set `webView.alpha = 0.0`, and then:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
        webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = 1000
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            webView.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The code worked fine at first time. But over time, I noticed that sometimes the text from the `webView` is loaded from the first page. Instead of showing  the last page that user stopped reading. Delay doesn't always help. If I use `Option 3` and make the delay value higher, 0.2 I see like at first, loading my first page and next `scrollview.webView` goes to the last reading page very quickly. I am trying to create something like a reading controller in the Apple Books app. I save `contentOffset.x` value and when the user open app again I show the page where user stopped reading the last time.

Comment: Hello! pleas check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561831/load-html-text-in-wkwebview these questions are related and no one can help me figure it out